# R Programming - Cross Table in R

Tags: r, crosstab

I have following data set. I would like to get following output based on the data. I tried aggregate and summaryBY functions, but didn’t get desired output.

[image: Data Set]

Desired out and Output of R using "Aggregate" function.

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Please, post your code. Is it homework? If so, please state that in your question. Also, read carefully these links to improve the quality of your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can use xtabs, with something like `xtabs(spend~age+gender,x)`

Answer (score 0):

If you turn it into a data.table, use dcast.

```
summary = dcast(df, agebin ~ gender, sum )
```